# The pipe 'limitTo' could not be found issue in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I created a custom pipe module and imported it in my custom module,but it's not working

**limit.pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'limitTo'
})
export class RcycLimitPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let limit = args ? parseInt(args, 10) : 10;
    let trail = '...';

    return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
  }

}
```

**limit.pipe.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RcycLimitPipe } from './rcyc-limit.pipe';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        RcycLimitPipe
    ],
    exports: [
        RcycLimitPipe
    ]
})
export class RcycLimitPipeModule { }
```

then I imported it in my custom modules.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChannelsComponent }   from './rcyc-channels.component';
import { routing } from './rcyc-channels.routing';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgxCarouselModule } from "ngx-carousel";
import { RcycChannelsService } from "./rcyc-channels.service";
import { RcycLimitPipeModule } from "../../rcyc-pipes/rcyc-limit/rcyc-limit.module";
import { RcycDefaultImagePipeModule } from '../../rcyc-pipes/rcyc-default-image/rcyc-default-image.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [routing,CommonModule,NgxCarouselModule,RcycLimitPipeModule,RcycDefaultImagePipeModule],
  declarations: [ChannelsComponent],
   providers: [RcycChannelsService]
})
export class ChannelsModule {}
```

but it still showing an error by telling that 'the limit and the 'defaultimage' could not be found.

this is my error

[image]

what the issue is here?please help me

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a separate module for your pipe? After all, you are really just importing `NgModule`, `CommonModule` (which you also import in your main module) and `RcycLimitPipe`.

You could simply remove `limit.pipe.module` altogether, import `RcycLimitPipe` in your main module and add it to its `declarations`.